# What does 狗血 mean as an adjective?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As a noun, it means the blood of a dog, which might be used for a lot of purposes, I guess, but not for makeup or health? Some Chinese-made TV dramas are often known as 剧情狗血,which is quite beyond me. Does that mean the plot of the drama is larger than life, like one Chinese villager can easily kill a number of Japanese soldiers?

And also if possible, you can tell me more about this animal or pet, because there are now many phrases in association with it, like 撒狗粮 or 单身狗 or 远光狗, Why do people use the word in this manner?

Comment: bkrs：狗血  1) dog blood 2) melodramatic contrived，examples 他被骂了个狗血喷头。
He was savagely reviled.
改
把他骂得狗血喷头
give him a severe scolding, jukuu:1.  let loose a stream of abuse against sb.
 狗血喷（淋）头

Comment: bkrs: 撒狗粮,выставлять романтические отношения напоказ (перед одиночками и холостяками) demonstrate romantic relationships (in front of unattached people) 
单身狗(Internet slang) person who is neither married nor in a relationship (used self-deprecatingly)

Comment: (高速)远光狗 drivers not turning down long distance
headlights when driving at night and thus causing discomfort to others,

Comment: bkrs：狗(5) 比喻坏人 [a bad person; evildoer] esp.走狗 running dog lackey; flunkey; stooge; servile follower

Comment: The thing that interests me is why they are known as 狗? What have they done to get this name? Is there any familiarity between such persons and the animal?

Comment: The thing that interests me is why they are known as 狗? What have they done to get this name? Is there any familiarity between such persons and the animal?

Comment: Can you explain the English phrase 'he is a lucky dog'? The same kind of idea in Chinese I guess.

Comment: just as in English "dog" can be used as substitute for "person" (often bad) see comment#4, re "lucky dog" see http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=+lucky+dog  幸运儿

Answer (score 2):

I think (洒)狗血 is from Taiwan originally. 狗血 could be short for 洒狗血.

洒狗血 could be interpreted in Chinese as 瞎搞 or 乱搞. In English, it could be something illogical, trying to be funny in a silly way, utter nonsense and etc.

So, 剧情狗血 could be the plot of the drama is ridiculous, utter nonsense, stupid and something like that.

撒狗粮 means a couple try to show how they love each other in front of a single person.

单身狗 means one who is single. So, you could say 在单身狗面前撒狗粮.

远光狗 refers to those always turning on the high headlight beams while driving, which dazzles vehicles from the opposite direction.

I don't usually hear 远光狗, 单身狗, 撒狗粮. I hear 剧情狗血 and 洒狗血 occasionally.

远光狗 is considered to be an insult, while 单身狗 and 撒狗粮 take some humorous effect I think.

Answer (score 1):

The word 狗血, or 洒狗血 is orginally used by people working on traditional operas to describe playing unnaturally in the old times.

In old times, some 道士 works as a ghost busters, after they do a lot of fancy works in the whole actions, they will pour a bowel of black dog blood. It is believed that dog blood can dissolve ghosts, which is really inconceivable, yet creative though.

For 相声, 洒狗血 means actors play freely, not follow scripts.

Nowadays, 狗血 means something is far away from what is normal.

狗 is usually refered to person that is not acting like a human, associate with either of bad behavior(远光狗), vile condition (单身狗), mean actions or simply anyone that you hate.

Answer (score 1):

In the 90s of last century, Hongkong TV series often captured supernatural works. One of the recurring plot is the ghost possessed to humans, people must  spill the dog's blood（狗血）to expel it. The Hongkong ghost movies and TV series  has become more and more popular, so there have been repeated use of this plot.  Then “狗血” is used to ridicule the immutable and stupid plot.

The dog of 远光狗...That's for swearing.

单身狗 means one who is single.In China, the term is commonly used for self-mockery.

Answer (score 1):

'狗血' is usually used by '剧情狗血',
It's means The story is bad and cheesy，easy to be guessed.

Answer (score 1):

"狗血” comes from English "够 s * * t", meaning s * * * ty enough, fully translated from Chinglish. Used to describe a subpar (overly exaggerated, drawn out, or otherwise) work or piece of entertainment.

单身狗 is just a humorous way for people to refer to their single status, lit. "single dog", hence the birth of "撒狗粮" where a couple "feed" all the single people "dog food" with their pda and tlc.

Answer (score 0):

- 狗血(gǒu xuè) A dog blood. It is imitated by constantly remake plot in TV, to describe those who often appear similar to the plot, parody, or very exaggerated false show Till now, it is often said excessive emotional performances and purposely to plot the dog blood.
- In our daily life, we see some very pretentious and contrived behaviors, also known as dog blood.